# Is it possible to use native libraries from ICS on older Android versions?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have to be able to play HLS stream on Android OS starting version 2.2. I have done a research of existing possibilities:

1. I can use some 3rd party stuff like [Vitamio](http://vov.io/vitamio/). It works, but the source is closed, performance is rather poor, their plug-in sends some user info somewhere to China and I don't want to bother our users by installing some 3rd party stuff... So that's not a good option from my perspective.
2. I can try to build some Android port of [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) framework, there are at least three of them, but I haven't been able to build at least one so far. I think it needs more patience and Googling... However, in case of success, there is also a problem with licensing - not as serious as with Vitamio and I am willing to pay license fees to MPEG LA if necessary, but it is still under LGPA.

Finally I got an Idea to use MediaPlayer from ICS, which already supports HLS streaming. My plan was to build the Android Stagefright media engine from the latest sources to get all the native libraries and distribute them together with my application.

I have successfully built all the Android stuff; got all the native libraries I need, but now I have a problem to load them on Froyo. I have placed the libraries into the projects libs folder, but application refuses to load them. It loads the original system libraries instead - if they are present on the current version.

So my question is, if it is possible to use native libraries from higher Android version on old ones. If so, then what I am doing wrong. How can I force my application to load ICS native libraries from its libs folder? Is it even possible?

Any comments, suggestions, ideas are highly appreciated...

Comment: Which way did you end up going? I need to do a similar thing.

Comment: I had to create my own player based on FFmpeg and ffplay.c sample in that library - 3 months of work... Try this tutorial: http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-for-android/ there is a build script which works on 100 percents. Also check the Dolphin player by Aatral Arasu: http://code.google.com/p/dolphin-player/ there you can find a lot of inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

You may try some opensource video player, such as VLC or mplayer, which has Android version.

And you can use ICS libraries, buy you need to do many work to modify and compile them with your target Android version. I've used some code from ICS in some of my apps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know there are solutions like VLC or mplayer, but - unfortunately, that's no option in my case. Customer wants his own solution without a mention about any 3rd party stuff except the statements required to comply with LGPL...I work on FFmpeg + SDL solution.

Comment: I meant you may find some solutions in the VLC for Android. You can use Android Surface to render pixels, and use AudioTrack to output audio. Just via JNI. The performance is good. I wrote VPlayer for Android.

Comment: You are the author of VPlayer? Great job man! Actually, I have two versions of my project. One is AudioTrack + jnigraphics, the second is SDL. Both use FFmpeg, which is fairly simple to use. The A/V decoding is not a problem at all, but there is one thing I am worry about - the A/V synchronization... I have no time to be a hero so I am trying to use "standard" FFmpeg + SDL solution... The performance is not a concern right now; I have a very limited time to deliver a working prototype so I must go the easiest way and possibly improve my solution in the future.